# What is left and right node where node may > 2

Tags: c++, tree, postorder

I can't seem to understand what is **left** and what is **right** node in tree.

Suppose I have a structure like this,

```
struct Rect
{
    void visit() { }
    std::vector<Rect*> components;
};
```

What is **left** and what is **right** in here? Is it present here? If so, how can I determine w/c is left and w/c is right?

I want to traverse them from root to parent (post-order)

Is this the right way?

```
void postorder(Rect *rect)
{
    if (rect == nullptr) return;

    for (auto &i : boost::adaptors::reverse(rect->components))
    {
        postorder(i);
    }

    rect->visit();
}
```

But left and right node aren't present here?

Comment: Who said that these terms apply for N-ary trees?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm searching in google for `post-order-tree-traversal` but all I can see is this kind of implementation. Nobody said it.

Comment: What makes you think then those terms apply?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I just thought it could be apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no left and right here (unless your rectangles are sorted by x-axis position, which isn't shown).